# Why is the square of an image not equvalent to taking the autoconvolution of an image in fourier space?

Tags: fourier-analysis, matlab, image-processing

Al right I know that in order to multiply in the normal domain I have to take the convolution in Fourier domain but when I do so in matlab and invert the result then I come up with nothing but a lot of noise (and a lot of complex numbers), the code I was using to do this was the following:

```
squaredImage=image.*image; %what I actually want 
fourierImage=fft2(image);
convolutionFourierImage=conv2(fourierImage,fourierImage);
notSquaredImage=ifft2(convolutionFourierImage); %this becomes a mess
```

Any idea why this code is not working?

Comment: Did you mean to do a 2-D FFT?

Comment: Tried it with fft2 as well and that didn't really improve things, I get a a lot of straight lines where I started with an image of a tiger.

Comment: You'll need to zeropad just like you would in the image domain. Also, you'll want to fftshift() prior to convolving so that DC is in the middle.